# Datetime-like index in `pandas`

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame loaded with a time series of cumulative rainfall:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, parse_dates=[['date', 'time']], dayfirst=True, index_col=0)
```

(I can't share the source data, it is read through an adapter object that presents the data as a text file with .csv content to `read_csv`, event though the source file is in some proprietary format - however, it's not related to the problem, the end result is DataFrame with a datetime index and floating point values - date could be dummied)

The rainfall is then converted resampled into minutes:

```
rainfall_differences = df['rainfall'].diff()
rainfall_differences = rainfall_differences.resample('1min', label='right', closed='right').sum()
```

All this works as expected. However, my question is about the difference between these two statements:

```
x = rainfall_differences.rolling('90min').sum()
y = rainfall_differences.rolling('1.5h').sum()
```

The first works, but the second throws an exception:

```
  File "<<path>>/my_file.py", line 68, in load_rainfalls
    result[duration_label] = rainfall_differences.rolling(duration_label).sum()
  File "<<path>>\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10386, in rolling
    closed=closed,
  File "<<path>>\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.validate()
  File "<<path>>\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1836, in validate
    freq = self._validate_freq()
  File "<<path>>\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1888, in _validate_freq
    f"passed window {self.window} is not "
ValueError: passed window 1.5h is not compatible with a datetimelike index
```

My question: why would a window of `'90min'` be compatible with a datetimelike index, when a window of `'1.5h'` is not, even though both evaluate into the identical value `Timedelta('0 days 01:30:00')` when passed to `pandas.to_timedelta()`?

Note: I'm aware of how to solve/work around the issue, but that's not my question. I'm wondering why this is even required. For example:

```
index_duration = str(int(pd.to_timedelta('1.5 hour').total_seconds() / 60)) + 'min'
y = rainfall_differences.rolling(index_duration).sum()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is necessary change `h` to `H`:

```
y = rainfall_differences.rolling('1.5H').sum()
```

I think reason is because not valid [`offset alias`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
Alias   Description
H       hourly frequency
T, min  minutely frequency
S       secondly frequency
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=5, freq='10T')
rainfall_differences = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5)}, index=rng)  
print (rainfall_differences)
                     a
2017-04-03 00:00:00  0
2017-04-03 00:10:00  1
2017-04-03 00:20:00  2
2017-04-03 00:30:00  3
2017-04-03 00:40:00  4

y = rainfall_differences.rolling('1.5H').sum()
print (y)
                        a
2017-04-03 00:00:00   0.0
2017-04-03 00:10:00   1.0
2017-04-03 00:20:00   3.0
2017-04-03 00:30:00   6.0
2017-04-03 00:40:00  10.0
```

Comment: Ah, so the answer is simply that functions like `to_timedelta()` allow for more different variants, while the Freqency string for `rolling()` must have a more strictly formatted string? Very unsatisfying, but it appears you are right `1.5h` does not work, `1.5H` does...

Comment: @Grismar - I think yes, it is 2 different things, here is `Frequency String` more `'strict'`